# How can I keep my Google Domain URL when forwarding it to my 000webhost website?

Tags: dns, hosting, web-hosting

So, I bought a domain from google domains and I’m hosting my website on 000webhost for free. I want to connect the google domain to 000webhost so I redirected, and when I type in my domain, it forwards to my hosted website. However, the url changes to the long url given by the host, and I don’t want that. Is there anyway to keep the domain url in the browser? (Preferably without url masking)

I forwarded the domain on google domains, but it changes the url.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, as the dns tag explains: DNS QUESTIONS MUST BE PROGRAMMING RELATED. Use this tag for programming questions related to writing code that interacts with the Domain Name System (DNS); for example, writing code that uses gethostbyname()